# git svn "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree directory"

Tags: git-svn

I have a git repo that was initially cloned from an svn repo.

When I tried a

> git svn rebase

I'm getting

> Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history

I have read pretty much every post here about this error and I tried

> git update-ref refs.remotes/git-svn refs/remotes/origin/master

I have also tried

> git svn rebase -l

I'm getting

> Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history

I am on git 1.7.11 msysgit.1

Thanks for the help :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

git-svn determines your remote repository by looking through your git log for "git-svn-id" entries in the commit messages.   It does this using `git rev-list --first-parent --pretty=medium HEAD`.  The first step to diagnosis is to run that command and inspect the log.

The `--first-parent` option tells it which branch to follow if it encounters a merge.  It won't follow all branches at that point, so it's likely that a rogue merge is to blame.  If that appears to be the case, use `git log --graph --all` to identify a "good" revision to roll back to - i.e. the most recent one with a "git-svn-id" in the log message.  What to do next depends on what you find!

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate it with option `--no-metadata`?

When I migrate my svn with `git svn clone --no-metadata`, I met the error message like you.
But, I re-migrated it without `--no-metadata` options, and then I could succeed in `git svn rebase`.